# I tried to open the arrays but I am getting the message called "No debugger available, can not send variable"

Tags: javascript, arrays, visual-studio-code

```
let obj = {'a':1,'b':2,'c':3,'d':4,
'student': {
    'name': 'nivedhna',
    'age': 24
}


};
let arr= [];
for(let value in obj){
    arr.push(value,obj[value])
}
console.log(arr)
```

Error:  (10) ['a', 1, 'b', 2, 'c', 3, 'd', 4, 'student', {…}]
No debugger available, can not send 'variables'

Comment: your code runs fine in a browser and nodejs ... you must be doing something you haven't shown

Comment: @JaromandaX - It was missing a [tag:visual-studio-code] tag. The error message is the error VSCode gives when you run a program in it to completion, then try to expand an array or other object in the output window.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're getting this error from VSCode in the Debug Console:

[image: VSCode Debug Console showing error "No debugger available, can not send 'variables'"]

To be able to expand the arrays in the Debug Console of VSCode, your program still has to be running. You're running the program and letting it finish entirely before trying to expand them, so the Debug Console can't connect to it to get the details (because the environment where the details were no longer exists).

Several options for you:

1. You can inspect the contents of the array by putting a breakpoint on the `console.log` statement (click in the left-hand gutter next to the line).

   [image: VSCode editor with cursor just left of the line numbers]

   When your program reaches that point, you can look at the array in the "locals" panel in the VSCode debugger:

   [image: VSCode "Variables" panel showing local variables]
2. You can add another `console.log` afterward and put a breakpoint on that, so that when the breakpoint is reached, you can expand the array in the Debug Console.
3. You can log a string instead of an array so that the full contents are shown to you: `console.log(JSON.stringify(arr, null, 4));` But it's not interactive.